# How to create a generic type on the Action delegate with a ByRef parameter?

Tags: c#, in-parameters

I am trying to create a delegate on an Action<> type with a by-ref parameter as argument. But I am stuck on how to achieve this.

That's what I got so far:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    struct MyStruct { }
    static void FooFn(in MyStruct s) { }
    delegate void Foo (in MyStruct s);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo f = FooFn;

        var t1 = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(MyStruct));
        var t2 = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(MyStruct).MakeByRefType());

        var d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(t1, null, f.Method);
    }
}
```

The issue with using "t1" in the delegate is, that the signature does not match. That is kindof expected, as I am passing the struct by reference.

t2 does not work either, as it complains that I can not use a By-ref parameter as argument list type. :(

Is there a way to create the delegate with to Foo in my example? Or do I *have* to drop the in-modifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot create an `Action<T>` with a by-ref parameter, because that aspect is *part of the delegate signature*, which is pre-defined and outside of your control. You will have to define your own delegate type, as you have done with `Foo`. This delegate type could be generic, but cannot declare variance - neither covariance nor contravariance is compatible with by-ref parameters (of the variant type).

Comment: Thanks, the hint "This delegate type could be generic" was kindof what I was missing :). Now I am almost at my goal... do you also happen to know how to get the non-ref type given you have a byref type? I.e. in my example above, how to get to "typeof(MyStruct)" if I have an instance of Type "MyStruct&"?

I mean, I _could_ do things like `Type.GetType(mytype.AssemblyQualifiedName.Replace("&", ""))`  but that is kindof... urks!

Comment: got it. `mytype.GetElementType()`